# How AtomicReference use CAS in case of Complex Object

Tags: java, multithreading, atomicreference

AtomicReference instance uses Unsafe CAS operation to leverage processor instructions for locking. But I am little bit confused how it works in case of complex object.

For example let us assume that I have an instance of Person class (id, firstName, lastName). I am sharing the object instance to multiple threads t1, t2 and t3. Since the operation should be atomic so instead of sharing Person class object instance I will wrap that object into AtomicReference instance and share that with all threads.

Now thread t1 is updating only firstName, thread t2 is updating only lastName and thread t3 is updating both firstName and lastName. After that every thread will call compareAndSet method to reflect the new changes.

Also I am using volatile reference so that write can happen in main memory and visible to all threads.

I want to understand:

1. In above scenario when compareAndSet get called, what are the things which will be compared between expected and new value for Person class instance(e.g. id, firstName, lastName)?
2. Suppose thread t1 has updated firstName and called compareAndSet. Thread t2 has updated lastName and just going to call compareAndSet. In this case how AtomicReference guarantees that thread t2 is not erasing out changes done by thread t1 i.e. updating firstName?
3. Suppose 2 threads t1 and t2 called compareAndSet at the same time then who will win the race and what will happen to other thread who losses?

Answer (score 5):

If you have shared mutable `Person` object, the `AtomicReference` will not help you at all. You need to make the `Person` immutable and create a new `Person` every time you want to apply changes. This way it doesn't matter how many fields your threads update. So suppose you have such immutable `Person` class:

```
public class Person {
    public final int id;
    public final String firstName, lastName;

    public Person(int id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Then your threads may do the following

```
AtomicReference<Person> ref; // shared reference

public void updateFirstName(String firstName) {
    Person curPerson, newPerson;
    do {
        curPerson = ref.get();
        newPerson = new Person(curPerson.id, firstName, curPerson.lastName);
    } while (!ref.compareAndSet(curPerson, newPerson));
}

public void updateLastName(String lastName) {
    Person curPerson, newPerson;
    do {
        curPerson = ref.get();
        newPerson = new Person(curPerson.id, curPerson.firstName, lastName);
    } while (!ref.compareAndSet(curPerson, newPerson));
}

public void updateName(String firstName, String lastName) {
    Person curPerson, newPerson;
    do {
        curPerson = ref.get();
        newPerson = new Person(curPerson.id, firstName, lastName);
    } while (!ref.compareAndSet(curPerson, newPerson));
}
```

Calling such methods you will update the `Person` as a whole and will not have any race conditions.

As for your third question, it's not specified, who will win, but the losing thread will just make one more iteration and update another field correspondingly, so you will eventually have the both fields updated.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of an [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) is to represent

> An object reference that may be updated atomically.

**It does nothing to prevent you from atomically modifying the object that reference is pointing to.**

> In above scenario when `compareAndSet` get called, what are the things
>   which will be compared between expected and new value for Person class
>   instance(e.g. id, firstName, lastName)?

None of those. [`compareAndSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html#compareAndSet-V-V-) will verify that the current reference is equal to the `expected` reference, using reference equality, ie. `==`. From the javadoc

> Atomically sets the value to the given updated value if the current
>   value `==` the expected value.

It doesn't know or care about the type of the reference and therefore doesn't know or care about its members or your logic in defining them.

> Suppose 2 threads t1 and t2 called `compareAndSet` at the same time then
>   who will win the race and what will happen to other thread who losses?

The order is undefined. `compareAndSet` will only work if the current reference is equal to the given expected reference. The method will return

> `true` if successful. `false` return indicates that the actual value was
>   not equal to the expected value.